# Different processes in different screens in python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have two different process running simultaneously and printing the output in the same console. What i require is, output of each process to be displayed in different screen.Say for example, i have main_process1 and main_process2.

main_process1 output should come in one screen and main_process2 should come in another screen. One option is telnet lib. Is there any other option?? Give some other suggestion.

I tried the following script,

```
from screenutils import list_screens, Screen
s4= Screen("session1",True)

s4.send_commands('bash')
s4.enable_logs()
s4.send_commands("df")
print next(s4.logs)
```

When i run this, i am not getting any output!Please help

Comment: Make the processes output to different files?

Comment: no, i am looking for different screens.

Comment: You likely either need to use `ncurses` or use a terminal multiplexer like `tmux` (here's a python API to tmux: http://tmuxp.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to run two seperate *scripts* that you want to execute and show their output on different screens (consoles)?

If so, [GNU Screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) is excellent for this. There is a fairly good [Introduction to screen](http://nathan.chantrell.net/linux/an-introduction-to-screen/) over at nathan.chantrell.net.

It's easy to install (`apt-get install screen` on debian, for example).

Comment: its kind of integrating two scripts into a new script.

Comment: How are they outputting to the same screen? Can you explain further?

Comment: through multiprocessing. say i have main1.py and main2.py, and i made Main.py with two processes. it will call main1.py and main2.py.

Comment: Why don't you use something like python's screenutils (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/screenutils) to control the screens, and call main.py in one screen and main2.py in the other. They will process in separate screens and you can connect to each individually. The python API to tmux that Kevin Stone mentioned about may be able to do the same thing.